# Find matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, linear-transformations

A linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ is given by

$T(i) = i+j; T(j) = 2i -j$.

With respect to the basis $\{i,j\}$, The matrix of $T = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\1 & -1\end{array}\right).$

What is the matrix of $T$ if the basis $\{i,j\}$ is replaced by $e_1 = (i-j)$
 and $e_2=3i+j$?

The solution is: $\left(\begin{array}{cc}-7/4 & -1/4 \\1/4 & 7/4\end{array}\right)$.

I am not able to come up with this solution. Here's my attempt:

$T(e_1) = T(i) - T(j) = i+j -(2i -j) = -i + 2j$

$T(e_2) = 3T(i) + T(j) = 3(i+j) +2i-j = 5i+2j$.

Thus, $T$ would be $\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1 & 5 \\2 & 2\end{array}\right)$.

---

Second Question:

If you let $T = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\1 & -1\end{array}\right).$ Then what is $T$ relative to $e_1,e_2$?

Comment: You have to express $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ in the basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T(i)=(1,1)$ and $T(j)=(2,-1)$ and $e_1=i-j=(1,-1)$ and $e_2=3i+j=(3,1)$, then $$T(e_1)=T(i-j)=T(i)-T(j)=(-1,2)=a_1e_1+b_1e_2 \,\text{(say)}$$ and $$T(e_2)=T(3i+j)=3(1,1)+(2,-1)=(5,2)=a_2e_1+b_2e_2\,\text{(say)}.$$ Thus the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the new basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2\\
b_1 & b_2
\end{pmatrix}$ and you need to find the values of $a_1,a_2,b_1$ and $b_2$. The above systems of equations reduces to $$a_1+3b_1=-1\\
-a_1+b_1=2$$ and

$$a_2+3b_2=5\\
-a_2+b_2=2.$$
Solve these equations to obtain $a_1=-\frac{7}{4},b_1=\frac{1}{4},a_2=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $b_2=\frac{7}{4}$.

Comment: My confusion is that I don't see why I shouldn't do this: $T(i) = (1,1) = a_1e_1 + b_1e_2$.$T(j) = (2,1) = a_2e_1+b_2e_2$. Solve for the $a$s and $b$'s.

Comment: $T = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a_1 & a_2 \\ b_1 & b_2\end{array}\right)$? Why? $T*e_1$ does not give you the correct answer.

Comment: @larry: Sorry I did not get you. Can explain more what are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

$e_1+e_2=4i$;$i=\frac{e_1+e_2}{4} = P(i |j)^T$;$e_2-3e_1=4j$;$j=\frac{e_2-3e_1}{4} = P(i| j)^T$.

Now compute the Matrix $P^{-1}$ and your $T$ in the new Basis is given by $P^{-1}TP$.

Comment: If you defined $T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\1 & -1\end{array}\right)$, and you wanted to find $T$ relative to new bases $e_1,e_2$ would T now be $\left(\begin{array}{cc} -.5 & 1.25 \\.5 & .25\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: T(i) = (1,1)' = a(e1) + b(e2), where a,b = -.5,.5. And you do something similar for T(j). Doesn't this give you T in a new bases?

Comment: I don't want to compute inverses for this problem. Second, the notation has changed and it's more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of the transformation of basis is:
$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3\\
-1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
P^{-1}=
\dfrac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-3\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Your transformed matrix is:
$$
P^{-1}TP=
\dfrac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-3\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3\\
-1&1
\end{bmatrix}=
\dfrac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
-7&-1\\
1&7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Added after comments.

[image]

The figure illustrate how operate the given transformation in the two basis.

Indices $\{i,j\}$ refer to the canonical basis, indices $\{1,2\}$ to the new basis $\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}$.

In the figure we have the vector $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v_{i,j}}=[1,2]^T$ (in canonical basis), that is transformed in $\mathbf{v'}=\mathbf{v'_{i,j}}=[5,-1]^T$.

In the new basis we have:
$$
\mathbf{v_{1,2}}= P^{-1}\mathbf{v_{i,j}}=
\dfrac{1}{4}\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
-5\\
3
\end {array}
\right]
$$
and, for the tranformed vector:
$$ \mathbf{v'_{1,2}}=
P^{-1}\mathbf{v'_{ij}}=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
2\\
1
\end {array}
\right]=
P^{-1}T_{i,j}\mathbf{v_{i,j}}=P^{-1}T_{i,j}P\,\mathbf{v_{1,2}}=T_{1,2}\mathbf{v_{1,2}}
$$
so we have:
$$
T_{1,2}=P^{-1}T_{i,j}P=
\dfrac{1}{4}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
-7&-1\\
1&7
\end {array}
\right]
$$

I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: What if you come across a problem where $P$ is not invertible? How would you get around this?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out what the $T$ is relative to $e_1,e_2$.

Comment: If $P$ is not invertible we hawe not a transformation of basis.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178772/… seems to be changing the basis of a transformation matrix, and it's not invertible.

Comment: What is $T$ relative to $e_1,e_2$?

Comment: $T$ transform a vector $v$ in a new vector $T(v)$ that is the same in any basis. The coordinates of the vectors are different in different basis, and the entries of the corrisponding matrix $T$ are different with different basis.

Comment: What is $T$ relative to $e_1,e_2$?

Comment: I don't undertand your question. Look at $P^{-1}TP$. This product of matrices, if applied to a vector $v$ whos components are in the new basis, perform a transformation $P$ from the new to the canonical basis, then tranform the resulting vector with $T$ , i.e. the transformation expressed in canonical basis components, then, with $P^{-1}$ return fron canonical to new basis. So $P^{-1}TP$ is the matrix that represent the same transformation as $T$ but for vector whose components are expressed in the new basis.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the same procedure as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178772/find-matrix-of-linear-transformation-relative-to-new-bases to find a way to represent $T$ in the basis ($e_1,e_2$). I'm sorry, but I just can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: If someone asked you to express the matrix $T$ relative to new bases $e_1$ and $e_2$, you would not be able to understand what they are asking for?

Comment: the matrix that represent $T$ in the new basis is obviously $P^{-1}TP$.

Comment: added a figure that can be helpful.